# Iptables multicast udp video forwarding

Tags: video, routes, multicast

I'm trying to configure a linux pc as a router for an ip RTSP camera.
     [IP cam] <----> eth1[Router PC]eth0 <-----> [Client]

The router should act as a NAT and portforwarding, for now I was able to configure it to forward the web port (80) on 8080 and RTSP (554) on the same 554 port.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.5:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 554 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.5:554
```

Now the camera sends the video stream multicast, (in particular on 239.0.0.15:15123), now I would also enable forwarding for multicast video stream. I just want that all the multicast udp packet that the camera send on eth1 should be redirect untouched to the client. 
 I have done a lot of research on the net and I have done so many tests, but I could not find a solution yet.
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance